What should df.plot(sharex=True) do?
I have trouble understanding sharex in pandas plotting. I can make it work using matplotlib, however I also tried the sharex argument to df.plot(). I don't know what it does, but it is not what I expect.
A simple example (with a Series, but the same happens with a DataFrame):
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


t = np.arange(0, 20, 0.01)
s = pd.Series(np.sin(t), index=t)

ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
ax2 = plt.subplot(212)
s.plot(ax=ax1, sharex=True)
s.plot(ax=ax2, sharex=True)
plt.xlim(0, 6)
plt.show()

The only effect I see is that the top chart hides its x axis labels. At the very least, I would expect both charts to limit their x axis to [0, 6], which now only happens for the bottom one. I also expect synchronized zooming.
The documentation says:

sharex : bool, default True if ax is None else False
In case subplots=True, share x axis and set some x axis labels
to invisible; defaults to True if ax is None otherwise False if
an ax is passed in; Be aware, that passing in both an ax and
sharex=True will alter all x axis labels for all axis in a figure.

What am I missing? Is this behavior 'correct'? What does "share x axis" actually mean? I would like to understand the design. I do not need a workaround.
I am not the only user who is confused.

It's not completely clear to me that anyone has thought through what this ought to do when subplots=False and sharex=True. It seems like it turns on the axis hiding behavior without turning on the x-axis sharing behavior, because Pandas does that during subplot creation, and you're handling that yourself.

Ah right, subplots=False! That's a clue.

Pandas devs should maybe only allow sharex or sharey to be set when subplots=True. Maybe open an issue at their github?

Done. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/60299

It worked for me doing this:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
ax2 = plt.subplot(212, sharex = ax1)
plt.xlim(0, 6)

as it said in this question: How to share x axes of two subplots after they have been created
you have to do:
sharex = ax1

to specify the axis to share.
In your case, if you don't want a workaround yo should specify the parameter:
subplots=True

as it said in the documentation: pandas.DataFrame.plot
In case subplots=True, share x axis and set some x axis labels to invisible; defaults to True if ax is None otherwise False if an ax is passed in; Be aware, that passing in both an ax and sharex=True will alter all x axis labels for all axis in a figure.
Hope it helps.

I am not looking for a workaround, this is not an answer to my question...

I edit the answer above, hope it helps.
